# How to count text based on other cell value in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, counting, countif

How to count text in Google sheet based on other cell value, I want to count Column B if Column C indicates that Column B have Duplicate Value in Column E like bellow. How I can count text.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In F2 try

```
=query(B2:C, "Select count(B) where B <> '' pivot(C)")
```

or if you want to count unique values for 'Done' and 'Duplicate' , in D3 try

```
=countunique(filter($B$2:$B, $C$2:$C=E$2))
```

and drag to the right for the duplicates count.

I hope that helps?

Comment: thanks its work. just one thing to add what if we want to count only Column B values I mean any formula that found duplicate entries in Column B and Counts only Duplicate entries  for ex : Column B has 3 duplicate values so is there any formula that counts these values and provides me number in column D. Hope you understand my point, thanks again for help .

Comment: In that case, you could try =countunique(ArrayFormula(if(countif(B2:B, B2:B)>1, B2:B,)))

Comment: Thanks Again its work, just last thing hope you don't mind, If I don't have values in column c " Not Process Yet" and there are only empty Cell in column C. So can we still count only duplicate values in column B after F as we already process and find duplicate value till E next have to process so can we count Column B for duplicate values when only from where C cell empty . as in above sheet if we remove all " Not Process Yet" values from C so we have only 1 duplicate value in Column B which is still Pending to processed, so hope you got my point . thanks again from the heart.

Comment: You means something like this ?=countunique(ArrayFormula(if(countifs(C2:C, "", B2:B, B2:B)>1, B2:B,)))

Comment: Thank You for help. God Bless You

Answer (score 1):

**D3** cell:

```
=COUNTIF(C2:C, D2)
```

[image: 0]

---

**E3** cell:

```
=COUNTIF(C2:C, E2)
```

[image: 0]

---

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(N(COUNTIFS(B2:B, B2:B, ROW(B2:B), "<="&ROW(B2:B))>1)))
```

[image: 0]